# JSON Object validation with JSONSchema Validator

Tags: jsonschema

```
const Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;

const validator = new Validator();

const obj = 
  [
    { 
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"Jack"    
    }
  ];

const instance= {    
      properties: {
        id: {
          type: 'number'
          },
          firstname: {
            type: 'string'
        }
      },
      required: ['id', 'firstname'],
      additionalProperties: false
};    
const  result = validator.validate(obj, instance);   
console.log(result.errors);
```

I want to validate a JSON Object using jsonschema Validator. when json object is not as per schema, then also validate function is not returning any error. irrespective of obj being as per schema/instance or not, its error section always returning null.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `obj` as an array as opposed to an object. As a result, validation is passing because you've used JSON Schema keywords which only apply to objects. (Many JSON Schema keywords are only applicable to specific types.)

In your schema, add `"type": "object"`, and you should see an error when the instance is not an object.

On a side note, an "instance" is the data you want to validate, and a "schema" is the JSON Schema you want to use for validation.